# .bat If Then Statement

Tags: batch-file, windows-scripting

I need help with writing a batch script for

```
if file newfile.txt exists
then  del "InDesignData.txt"
ren "newfile.txt" "InDesignData.txt"
```

Comment: Removed salutations: "Thanks in advance, \n  Joe", don't do it next time

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if not exist newfile.txt goto skip
del "InDesignData.txt"
ren "newfile.txt" "InDesignData.txt"
:skip
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response!

Works Great!

Comment: yours was all I needed nothing more

Answer (score 10):

You can use simple curved brackets (also supporting else!)

```
@echo off
IF EXIST newfile.txt (
del "InDesignData.txt"
ren "newfile.txt" "InDesignData.txt"
)
```

With else:

```
@echo off
IF EXIST newfile.txt (
del "InDesignData.txt"
ren "newfile.txt" "InDesignData.txt"
) else (
echo Making tea
)
```

Answer (score 4):

You could do it several ways, the cleanest methods would be:

On a single line:

```
if exist newfile.txt del "InDesignData.txt" & ren "newfile.txt" "InDesignData.txt"
```

On separate lines:

```
if exist newfile.txt del "InDesignData.txt"
if exist newfile.txt ren "newfile.txt" "InDesignData.txt"
```

Or using ( )

```
if exist newfile.txt (
    del "InDesignData.txt"
    ren "newfile.txt" "InDesignData.txt"
)
```

Using the brackets is an improvement over using GOTO because it is much cleaner code. (It's just not usually what I think of first because I learned BATCH under MS-DOS.)

I can't think of a reason to use the GOTO statement, unless you are using and ancient version of Windows. And in THAT case I would only use the **GOTO** statement if what you are testing for (in this case if newfile.txt exists) is changed (say, deleted in this case) in the first **IF** statement. The **GOTO** statement tends to make reading the script later more difficult.

Comment: _On separate lines_ I would recommend to use parenthesis `if condition ( line1 NEWLINE line2 )`

Comment: Yes, that's another way to do it.

Comment: Edited your code, there should be not `exist` in front of `del` and `ren`

Comment: @Mogli, +1 for for pointing that out. I don't know what I was thinking or how I missed it. Someone rejected your edit, so I changed it. I hope the +1 is acceptable payback! :)

Comment: Thank you Kruug. I don't know how those `exist`'s keep getting put back!

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this is to is to have if statements and labels for both error and success and use ECHO to debug it... my example here has to do with directories, but surely you can adapt for you file deletion/creation needs:

```
    ECHO Cleaning up folders...
    if exist %myDir% goto deleteFolder
    goto createNewDir

    :deleteFolder
    echo Deleting %myDir%
    RMDIR %myDir% /S /Q
    IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO Error


    :createNewDir
    mkdir %myDir%
    IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO Error
    goto Done

    :error
    echo something went wrong
    goto End

   :Done
    echo Success!

   :End
```

HTH, 
EB